# Remove Shipping Costs for specific products

Tags: magento-1.9

We have a selection of products for which do not require shipping costs. How do I apply this in Magento, so that when these products are added to basket, there is no shipping cost upon checkout?

Comment: Is your product shippable?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it, you said "a selection of products for which do not require shipping costs", means you need to offer free shipping for specific products of your choice. Here is the complete, brief and easy solution for you. With the help of below article, you can assign free of cost shipping to as many products as you want:

http://immense.net/magento-free-shipping-certain-products/